# What the meaning of "?" in the PHP URL

Tags: url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “?” symbol in URL used for in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574493/what-is-the-symbol-in-url-used-for-in-php)

In the websites based on PHP usually has "?" in URL,
i.e. http://host/wordpress/?p=276

What is the meaning of "?" in the URL?

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It separates the URL path from the query string.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator

Answer (score 3):

The "?" is not related to PHP only. This is the symbol which starts the begining of query. Format is:

```
www.serverhost.com/script.php?parameter1=A&parameter2=B
```

When browser requests server with this query the server parses it and passes parameters to the script, for example in PHP you will receive those parameters in $_GET array, i.e:

$_GET['parameter1'] will contain 'A', and $_GET['parameter2'] will contain 'B'.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574493/what-is-the-symbol-in-url-used-for-in-php

Answer (score 0):

It's using GET to store a variable called p with a value of 277.

In PHP you can read that variable by running

```
<?
echo $_GET['p'];
?>
```

On this page that would say 277.

In this case, it's used to mean this is post number 277. The code will check this is a number, then look up the post with id 277 in the database.

Answer (score 0):

seperation of http address and parameters passed to that address

Answer (score 0):

? indicates the beginning of the query part of the URI. Please refer [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-23)

Answer (score 0):

When the forms (like login or register or any other kind of forms) are sending values )onclick of submit button) if that form is sent by 'GET' method then the values sent are visible in URL with appending '?' at the end and values next to that