# what does a question mark mean before a php form action

Tags: php

```
<form action="?login" method="POST">
<button>Login with Google</button>
</form>
```

I have seen many different actions for a form action that must usually point to a php file ro ... but what does the ?login mean

more information : This is from the openid library and after the button is clicked it goes to a google allow page! and after our login is complete the button will not be shown! what does this mean ?

After the answers I know what the ?login does but why doesen't the button be shown after the login has completed  ???

Full code :

```
<?php

require 'openid.php';
try {
# Change 'localhost' to your domain name.
$openid = new LightOpenID('localhost');
if(!$openid->mode) {
    if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
        $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
        header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
    }
?>
<form action="?login" method="post">
<button>Login with Google</button>
</form>
<?php
} elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
    echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
} else {
    echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' has ' : 'has not ') .                    logged in.';  
}
  } catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Comment: It submits the form to the same page as the form is at, but it calls the function: `if(isset($_GET['login'])) { echo $_GET['some_form_name'] }` so basically your-php-file-with-a-form.php?login

Comment: But whats the reason that the button will not be shown ?

Comment: Which button will not be shown? when how? be more specific, show some examples.

Comment: @user2691882: It isn't? See [the live demo](http://goo.gl/FDvcoC)

Comment: The button that has login with google ! doesn't get shown , I uploaded it to dota2tradebots.com/googlelogin.php look there thats a full example

Answer (score 4):

This is a query string parameter. It means that the form should be submitted to the current script url, but a ?login parameter should be appended

The script than sends a redirect header to send the user to the google login page.

Comment: This is useful when you want to send both GET and POST variables. You put the GET variables in the query string as name value pairs and let the form create the POST. `action="?login=1&page=home"`

Answer (score 1):

It is just the part of the (relative) URL that indicates the start of a query string.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, it means that your form will be submited to the actual page with the query parameter appended.

If you are on page `example.com/login.php` and you submit this form, it will be sent at the page `example.com/login.php?login` which is useful if, for example you want to validate the input before redirecting to another page.

See [what is ? in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000611/what-the-meaning-of-in-the-php-url/6000770#6000770)

A short example would be something like

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['login'])){
    // validate the login form
    // if the form is valid, redirect to the logged in page 
    // else show any type of error message
}

// The regular page in itself displayed the same as before the form submitting
// with an added error message if needed
```

Answer (score 0):

this means submitting the form on the same PHP script with additional query string. e.g if the  form file name is abc.php then after submit URL become abc.php?login where you can get login in GET